# Why Xamarin.Forms bindings do not work with default accessors?

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have a property

```
    public List<WebApi.UserChatRto> Chats {
        get; set;
    }
```

that I bind to a ListView

```
       <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Chats}">
```

That works. Now if I change the property declaration to

```
    public List<WebApi.UserChatRto> Chats;
```

the listview will be empty.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding only works with **properties**, not with **fields**.

> **Reference** https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/